# Looping through columns (Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Feeling stuck!
I've created a roster sheet that allows you to input individuals via prompt. However, I would like to change the background color of cells based on what is entered. So far, only the first cell is changed upon being entered.

Here is a snippet, any help is appreciated!

````
  var newEntryRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow();
  var newEntryCol = 1;
  var newMemberCell = spreadsheet.getRange(newEntryRow,newEntryCol);

  for (var i = 0; i < getLastCol; i++) {
    var data = newMemberCell.getValue();
    var bgColor = "#FFFFFF";
      
        switch (data) {
            case "Active":
                bgColor = "#A8D08D";
                break;
            case "Inactive":
                bgColor = "#9CC2E5";
                break;
            case "Standby":
                bgColor = "#FFD965";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        
        newMemberCell.setBackground(bgColor);
        newEntryCol++;
    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'newMemberCell' is been assigned just once, with 'newEntryCol === 1'. Try to move the line that creates the 'newMemberCell' to inside the for block, so it will create a 'newMemberCell' for each loop.

```
 var newEntryRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow();
 var newEntryCol = 1;
  
 for (var i = 0; i < getLastCol; i++) {
    var newMemberCell = spreadsheet.getRange(newEntryRow,newEntryCol);
    var data = newMemberCell.getValue();
    var bgColor = "#FFFFFF";
  
    switch (data) {
        case "Active":
            bgColor = "#A8D08D";
            break;
        case "Inactive":
            bgColor = "#9CC2E5";
            break;
        case "Standby":
            bgColor = "#FFD965";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    newMemberCell.setBackground(bgColor);
    newEntryCol++;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.